# How can I zoom the Azure Maps bounding box on cluster click event?

Tags: azure, bing-maps, azure-maps

A data source in Azure Maps can cluster point features (pins) within a certain radius. When a click event on such a cluster occurs I would like to reset my bounding box to the area represented by the cluster and zoom in to show individual pins within the cluster.

With Google Maps you can set the default behaviour of a cluster to auto zoom on click. This feature was also relatively easily accomplished in the old [Bing Maps API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750348.aspx). How can I add this functionality in Azure Maps without an unwieldy amount of JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it appears Azure Maps does not support it directly, the following approach could be considered:

Once we layer is clicked `event` returns *pixel position* of target object along with another properties. Then `min` and `max` coordinates of cluster circle is determined via `atlas.Map.pixelsToPositions function`:

```
const coordinates = e.map.pixelsToPositions([
          [e.pixel[0] + (clusterRadius*2), e.pixel[1] + (clusterRadius*2)],
          [e.pixel[0] - (clusterRadius*2), e.pixel[1] - (clusterRadius*2)],
        ]);
```

Then the bounds of area which might contain pins within a cluster bubble is determined via [`atlas.data.BoundingBox.fromPositions` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.data.boundingbox?view=azure-iot-typescript-latest#frompositions-position---):

```
const bounds = atlas.data.BoundingBox.fromPositions(coordinates);
```

And finally map viewport is set:

```
 map.setCamera({
          bounds: bounds,
          padding:0
        });
```

Here is [a demo](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/mQRKQg) for your reference

Comment: Here is another demo that also does this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Bubble%20Layer/Point%20Clusters%20in%20Bubble%20Layer.html

It uses the getClusterExpansionZoom function to get the zoom level to go to for the cluster to break apart.

Comment: Here is a link to a live version of the sample I linked to: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Point%20Feature%20Clustering